# How to remove shadow of Tab navigator on Android?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

React tab bar navigator keeps displaying a shadow bar. I do not want a border or a shadow above the tab navigator

**In my emulator this happens**

[image]

**Expected behaviour**

[image]

**I have tried**

```
style: {
            elevation: 0, // remove shadow on Android
            shadowOpacity: 0, // remove shadow on iOS
            shadowOffset: {
                width: 0, height: 0 // for iOS
            },
        },
        indicatorStyle: {
            width: 0, height: 0, elevation: 0,      
        }
```

and

```
style: {
            borderTopWidth: 0,
            elevation: 0
          }
```

and

```
<Tabs tabContainerStyle={{ elevation:0}}></Tabs>
```

and `ShadowVisible: false,` and a bunch of other things

Comment: Could you provide a minimum reproducible example? Something I can work with?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito  Do you mean how i expect the code to behave? I want the border (border/shadow) that shows up in my emulator to not be visible

Comment: No I mean something like a codepen for react-native...